# scrapy: transport item over several parse and collect data

Tags: python, scrapy

I just tried for the first time to populate a item while transport it from page to page.

It works in each loop and the gender information also arrives correctly in parse_3 but g2 doesnt fit the category of the response url and g1 (first category level) is always the last element of the list from the list i loop through in parse_sub ...

For sure I do something wrong, but I can't find the problem, it would be great if somebody could explain me how it works.

Best,
Jack

```
class xspider(BaseSpider):
    name = 'x'
    allowed_domains = ['x.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.x.com']

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        maincats = hxs.select('//ul[@class="Nav"]/li/a/@href').extract()[1:3]
        for maincat in maincats:
            item = catItem()
            if 'men' in maincat:
                item['gender'] = 'men'
                maincat = 'http://www.x.com' + maincat
                request = Request(maincat, callback=self.parse_sub)
                request.meta['item'] = item
            if 'woman' in maincat:
                item['gender'] = []
                item['gender'] = 'woman'
                maincat = 'http://www.x.com' + maincat
                request = Request(maincat, callback=self.parse_sub)
                request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request

    def parse_sub(self, response):
        i = 0
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        subcats = hxs.select('//ul[@class="sub Sprite"]/li/a/@href').extract()[0:5]
        text = hxs.select('//ul[@class="sub Sprite"]/li/a/span/text()').extract()[0:5]
        for item in text:
            item = response.meta['item']
            subcat = 'http://www.x.com' + subcats[i]
            request = Request(subcat, callback=self.parse_subcat)
            item['g1'] = text[i]
            item['gender'] = response.request.meta['item']
            i = i + 1
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request

    def parse_subcat(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        test = hxs.select('//ul[@class="sub"]/li/a').extract()
        for s in test:
            item = response.meta['item']
            item['g2'] = []
            item['g2'] = hxs.select('//span[@class="Active Sprite"]/text()').extract()[0]
            s = s.encode('utf-8','ignore')
            link = s[s.find('href="')+6:][:s[s.find('href="')+6:].find('/"')]
            link = 'http://www.x.com/' + str(link) + '/'
            request = Request(link, callback=self.parse_3)
            request.meta['item'] = item
            yield request

    def parse_3(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        print item
```

Comment: It would be helpful to know the actual domain you are crawling.  Are you really crawling x.com?

Comment: no :), but it should not matter, the problem seems to be that the only the last element in the url list gets yielded and overwrites the information from before :(

Comment: try putting `yield item` instead of `print item` then see , if your debug us on scrapy will print the yield items on the screen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def parse_subcat(self, response):
    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
    test = hxs.select('//ul[@class="sub"]/li/a').extract()
    for s in test:
        item = response.meta['item']
        item['g2'] = []
        item['g2'] = hxs.select('//span[@class="Active Sprite"]/text()').extract()[0]
        s = s.encode('utf-8','ignore')
        link = s[s.find('href="')+6:][:s[s.find('href="')+6:].find('/"')]
        link = 'http://www.x.com/' + str(link) + '/'
        request = Request(link, callback=self.parse_3)
        request.meta['item'] = item
        yield request
```

response doesn't contains meta but request so
insted of `item = response.meta['item']`
it should be `item = response.request.meta['item']`